# How to convert a list of hyperlinks into friendly names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of hyperlinks (a new link in each cell). I want to take each hyperlink and update it so that the link displayed is instead a friendly name (e.g. going from 'https://example.com' to a link that's just 'example').

I've tried doing =HYPERLINK(https://example.com, [example]), hoping that this would work and I could drag this formula down, but it didn't work. Please advise.

I have excel version 16.61

Comment: `=HYPERLINK("https://example.com", "example")`

Comment: Assuming your first link is stored in range A1, try this: `=HYPERLINK(A1,IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-1),FIND(".",A1)+1,999),A1))`